# Can we call onSavedInstanceState() from onPause?

Tags: android

It is about an email application.

Suppose a user is composing an email and the activity suddenly enters the paused state. Now the user expects the partially composed email message (draft email) to be saved if they leave the activity and resumed when they get back to it.

How is it accomplished?

If it were about the activity being destroyed, I knew that the state would be saved in a bundle returned by onSaveInstanceState(). This is something related to onDestroy().

But how is this state going to be saved in onPause() method?

Comment: if the activity doesn't get destroyed, it won't loose its state...
There is no need to handle it, because the text will still be there when the user comes back. Have you tried it out?

Comment: (if it's in the background (still alive) and then gets killed due to lack of memory or a task killer or something, onSaveInstanceState() will be called...there is a reason for when it is called...)

Comment: @jpm: Please read the first paragraph after the second code snippet on this webpage [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html).

It says: "The only time you should persist user changes to permanent storage within onPause() is when you're certain users expect the changes to be auto-saved (such as when drafting an email). "

This means that we can save user changes to permanent storage in onPause(). Do they mean database by permanent storage?

Comment: yeah, permanent storage means a database or filesystem.
I don't think it's necessary to do anything in this situation (as long as onSaveInstanceState is not called, since the data in your activity won't get lost until it's called...